# jquery-ui button inside jquery datatable

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables with theme roller support, and I would like to place a jquery-ui button in a column for each row. In order to do this, I'm using the following code:

```
oTable = $('#balances').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    ...
    "aoColumns": [
        ...
        {
            "mData": null,
            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                return $("<div />")
                    .append($("<button id='detail'>Details</button>").button())
                    .html();
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The buttons are drawn and I can attach events to them, but it seems that I'm missing something (for example, these buttons don't animate when you move the mouse over them).
How can I correct this? Is there a better way to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm using classes and I cannot style the input type buttons with I have tried this $(".btn, input[type=button], a, button, .editUserBtn").button(); at the end of the ready. The only buttons that style are the ones not added dynamically ... Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because using multiple identical Ids is not recommended, I'd suggest using a class instead, and moving the .button() call further down in the code:

```
oTable = $('#balances').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    ...
    "aoColumns": [
        ...
        {
            "mData": null,
            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                return $("<div />")
                    .append($("<button class='detail'>Details</button>"))
                    .html();
            }
        }
    ]
});
$("button.detail").button();
```

Comment: Thanks Marty, I've tried your suggestion but for some reason with $("button") I can't select the buttons inside the data table... only the existing buttons outside the table are in the collection.